# What are the best way to launch client exe?

Tags: asp.net, client, exe

I am creating a web application which need to launch "NXClient" at client machine. So what are the best way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: I need some clarifications. You want your user to visit your website, and in doing so launch an application that already exists on their machine?

Comment: I am creating a website which need to interact within cloud i.e access remote machine. This remote machine will be access using application i.e. NXclient. This will already installed on users machine so I need to launch this client exe using my website so user can provide login credentails and access the remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

Instead, you can associate an extension with your program on the client, then serve a file with that extension, and the program will open it.

Comment: +1 "...will open it **if the user allows it to** " As it should be.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited to remove a suggestion that works only in IE, and with annoying prompts at that...**

To launch it without user interaction is, as @SLaks says, impossible from pure ASP.NET, and for good reason.

However, you can create an ActiveX control or browser add-on in another language, and have the user install it.  However, by definition, that's not an ASP.NET solution, it's an ActiveX solution, or an add-on solution, etc.

Arguably, however, even such browser add-ons are a bad idea, and you need to be very careful not to do it in an insecure way, and should explicitly state what your add-on does.

Comment: Really?  Which one won't work... The link, or the add-on?  I'll gladly retract my answer if it's wrong...

Comment: The link.  I'm reasonably certain that browsers will block it.  Also, it is likely to copy the EXE to `%TEMP%`.

Comment: @SLaks.  You're mostly right.  It works in IE, but not Firefox. Safari, or Chrome.  Go figure.