# How can I open an .EXE file from an ASP.NET site?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, executable

Can I open executable files on a client machine from an ASP.NET site hosted on IIS?

I have tried using the following code in ASP.NET:

```
Process notePad = new Process();

notePad.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
notePad.StartInfo.Arguments = @"E:\abc.txt";

notePad.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
notePad.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
notePad.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

notePad.Start();
```

and also in Javascript with the following code:

```
function Launch() {
    var w = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    w.run('notepad.exe');
    return true;
}
```

But both snippets will only open the file when the site is not hosted in IIS.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would you ever possibly want to do this? Something is seriously broken with your application and your respect for security if you think this is even an acceptable option.

Comment: I agree with Cody that you shouldn't do this. However, I also understand that in many environments users (mainly corporate users) like stuff done for them like this. If anything though, you should use the Response stream to transfer file data and allow the operating system (i.e. Windows) to associate any file with the correct program to handle it.

Comment: Actually that is as per requirement, I have given. I want to know whether it is really possible or not(overriding Security issues). Also have one point, if that Executable resides on Shared Drive, then Will it possible?. I dont think so it is possible.

Comment: [Possible Repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547372/what-are-the-best-way-to-launch-client-exe)

Comment: @bitxwise: Had *that* been your answer, I'd have upvoted it to the moon. That's *exactly* how you should handle this type of situation, and one of the perks of doing things the "right way" is that they're far less likely to break. For example, when one of your users has a Mac or has replaced "notepad.exe" with "notepad++.exe".

Comment: @Swapnil: Is it NOTEPAD, specifically? Or another program?

Comment: Its actually "Design.exe" file and will not change its name also. Regarding Barcode printing.

Comment: @Swapnil: Regarding Shared Drive executables, keep in mind how executables, even your code (once deployed) runs. It can make references to external libraries that may not be on the client machine (i.e. registered in the GAC on Windows). So I would not recommend that either.

Comment: @Swapnil: Even if it doesn't change its name, it may change its location on the client machine may be different. You'd be counting on the user having it on the client AND in the same location as your path OR that the installed path is registered in the user's environment paths.

Comment: @Swapnil: If user is only using IE and the pathing issue has been addressed (see my comment above), then it should work. I've also updated my answer below.

Comment: What if the user changes the path of their network drive? Hope your IT department isn't very busy.

Comment: @bitxwise: As you have suggested to provide file to download, user need to install it. But in my case if whenever user clicks on link it should directly opens the application.

Comment: @Swapnil: That's exactly what I was hoping would happen. As I said in my answer below, the file extension tells the OS which program to use to open the file.

Comment: Well the problem with your first approach is that no code you ever run on the Server (ASP.NET) is going to open an executable on the client, which is a completely separate machine.

Comment: Your second problem, is this is a massive security hole, if it were allowed. Can you imagine what would happen if instead of opening pop-ups websites could run arbitrary programs on your machine? Put simply, if you need to open notepad from a web page directly, you are doing it wrong. Go back to the drawing board.

Comment: @JohnFX: We've already told him this is a no-no, but it's a requirement so...bummers =)

Comment: @bitxwise: I've heard that line before. Somehow I doubt the requirement was "Spawn an EXE from a website". Even if it was, just because the requirements say they need a gun that attaches to a boot, doesn't mean we should deliver.

Answer (score 2):

You will **not** be able to launch an executable on the Client (the computer running the Browser) under pretty much any circumstance...

Your code which is in C# which lives on the server which looks like it is trying to run Notepad if working would actually be opening Notepad instances on the server...not the client.

If you did manage to allow the Client to give you permissions to run Notepad (a big if), you'd probably also want to show something if the machine wasn't a windows PC (e.g. not having Notepad in the first place)

Comment: I say Not but if you uncheck enough security settings and add enough references into trusted sources on each client machine, you might be able to open notepad...

Comment: But please don't. There's a distinction between web applications and desktop applications for a reason.

Comment: I was trying to imply that it's impracticable in every possible way, but technically possible (technically)...

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Javascript but this only works for IE users:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Run Executable HTA</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function RunEXE(prog)
    {
        var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        oShell.Run('"'+prog+'"', 1);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="btnMyButton" onClick="RunEXE('notepad.exe')" type="button" value="Notepad" />
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Removed hardcoding

**EDIT**

*Updating answer as OP is trying to use Design.exe.*

As I said, I would prefer NOT to do this, but as it is a requirement, let's see what we can do. Instead of trying to open Design.exe and pass it which file to load, assuming that Design.exe files have their own file extension (i.e. .txt, .des), perhaps you can use the Response stream to transfer the file and when the user opens the download, Windows (assuming that's the OS) will automatically use Design.exe to open the file?

Comment: **DO NOT HARDCODE THE PATH TO NOTEPAD.**

Comment: Yeah, it's an example of a commonly repeated, albeit mistake, concept. Showing this as an example just encourages other developers to make the same mistake. It's a sad reality that the majority of people just copy and paste code they find online. Examples like this are neither informative nor good for the community.

Comment: Updated without hardcoding. I still think people in this community are too anal about EXAMPLES (not "here is the exact code that you need"), but hey, whatever helps =) Sleep better!

Comment: @bitxwise: Obviously *I* know better than to copy and paste code that I find online into a production project, but I'm also aware enough to know that not everyone else sees things that way. My original point was that your "example" was poor because it perpetuates a common bad practice. Even if you do know better, you can't assume everyone else does. Either way, I've removed my downvote since you've revised the code.

Comment: @Cody: Noted. I agree, various cultures need to change. Although I've always been in the school of encouraging good practices over damning the bad =) Anyway, thanks for not letting me be lazy w/ the example. Cheers.

Comment: @bitxwise:ActiveX is only supported by IE.What about other browsers?

Comment: @santosh: Yeah, doing a quick search, seems like a repeat on SO. I'll post a comment to the user's question directly addressing this. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

If absolutely must do this, and I suggest you don't...

**Option 1:**
If you only need to support IE, one option is to build a small ActiveX control with a button that shells out to the desired program and embed it in the web page.

**Option 2:**
If you are trying to open a specific file in whatever design.exe is, and the users have a file type you want to open registered to that app on their systems you could just put a link to the file with the appropriate extension on the web page and it will open the app with that file in it.

Comment: I may have tried Option 2, I added file extension in configuration of Site. But it does not launch the application's window. Process only runs in background (shows in Task manager).

Comment: I think you might benefit from reading up on how websites work. Any changes you make on the web-server won't affect behavior on the client. You need to make sure the file type is registered on the USER'S (client) machines. Not the server.

Comment: Yes I know that, yet I tried that. For Option 1, If I add reference of Executable in ActiveX , Will it directly launch application?.

Comment: It will do whatever the code in your ActiveX control tells it to do. When a user installs your ActiveX control and allows it to be used by the browser they are basically giving it permission to do whatever the logged in user can do. The browser (and thus JavaScript) generally try to prevent that or else you could do horrible things to anyone's machine that hit your website. Also, I still don't think you understand. There is no "configuration of the site" on the user's machine, so I don't see how you made the change in the right place.

Comment: Ok Thanks ... I will try for that option.

Comment: FYI: Option 2 is a much less complex option and is definitely preferable. Especially if you are trying to open a specific FILE in that application.